# Can't extract JSON Paths in Queries

Tags: mysql, sql, json, phpmyadmin

Hi I have a table "status" with 2 column `id` and `string`. 
I insert one data for example `id = 1` and `string = {"1": "Enable", "2": " Disabled"}`.

How can I only get the value "Enable" in SQL?

```
If I type SELECT
  id, string->"$.1" 
FROM status;
```

I have Invalid JSON Path expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to to wrap the `1` in quotation marks so it is treated as a string, not a number.

Either of these should work for you:

```
SELECT   id, string->"$.\"1\""  
FROM status
```

or:

```
SELECT   id, string->'$."1"' 
FROM status
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a function for that called `json_extract()`.
Following query should get the job done:

```
   SELECT
      id, 
    json_extract(string,'$.1') 
    FROM status;
```

**Edit**: This solution will only work for Mysql 5.7 or later versions.

Hope it helps!

Comment: It doesnt work. Like @Ike Walker said I need to wrap the 1 in quotation marks.

Comment: Sorry. Forgot to check the Mysql version with you.